# Rust tokio infinite loop for multiple buttons listening

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm new to Rust and I'm struggling to understand how to use `tokio` with blocking code in infinite loops. I have two buttons attached to my Raspberry Pi 3 and I want to listen to *either* button being pressed. I'm using the `rust_gpiozero` crate for this.

Here is the button code:

```rust
use rust_gpiozero::*;
let mut button = Button::new(19);
button.wait_for_press(None); // blocking here
```

I don't know how to continuously listen for either button in the main code. I think I should be using `tokio::task::spawn_blocking` but I'm not sure how. Something like this:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
  let b1_blocking_task = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
    let mut button = Button::new(19);
    button.wait_for_press(None); // blocks here
  });

  let b2_blocking_task = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
    let mut button = Button::new(26);
    button.wait_for_press(None); // blocks here
  });

  loop { // forever listen for button presses
     tokio::select! {
       _ = b1_blocking_task => {
           println!("Button 1 pressed")
       }
       _ = b2_blocking_task => {
           println!("Button 2 pressed")
       }
     };
  }
}
```

The code above doesn't work, but what's the best strategy for how to do this properly?

Comment: use a channel and loop in your spawned task.

Comment: Hi Stargateur, appreciate the response. I'm not sure I follow, do you mean put each `wait_for_press` function in its own loop{} with a channel send call after?

Answer (score 3):

A small change to your code will make it work:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let b1_blocking_task = || {
        tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
            let mut button = Button::new(19);
            button.wait_for_press(None); // blocks here
        })
    };

    let b2_blocking_task = || {
        tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
            let mut button = Button::new(26);
            button.wait_for_press(None); // blocks here
        })
    };

    loop {
        // forever listen for button presses
        tokio::select! {
          _ = b1_blocking_task() => {
              println!("Button 1 pressed")
          }
          _ = b2_blocking_task() => {
              println!("Button 2 pressed")
          }
        };
    }
}
```

This will spawn a new thread for each button press. It isn't particularly efficient, but probably also unlikely to matter too much if these are user input events anyway.

You can make it better by just spawning each thread once, and using channels to communicate between them:

```
use tokio::sync::mpsc::channel;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // pick suitable queue sizes for these channels
    let (mut b1_sender, mut b1_receiver) = channel(16);
    let (mut b2_sender, mut b2_receiver) = channel(16);

    let b1_blocking_task = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
        let mut button = Button::new(19);
        button.wait_for_press(None); // blocks here
        // will panic if the channel queue gets full
        b1_sender.try_send(()).unwrap();
    });

    let b2_blocking_task = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
        let mut button = Button::new(26);
        button.wait_for_press(None); // blocks here
        // will panic if the channel queue gets full
        b2_sender.try_send(()).unwrap();
    });

    let (_, _, _) = tokio::join!(
        b1_blocking_task,
        b2_blocking_task,
        tokio::task::spawn(async move {
            loop {
                // forever listen for button presses
                tokio::select! {
                    Some(_) = b1_receiver.recv() => {
                        println!("Button 1 pressed")
                    }
                    Some(_) = b2_receiver.recv() => {
                        println!("Button 2 pressed")
                    }
                    else => break
                };
            }
        })
    );
}
```

---

The API that you are using is not ideal because it *requires* that you create blocking threads. It would be much better if there was instead some way to poll the button to see if it has been clicked. Internally, the crate seems to be doing that so it should be possible for it to expose the mechanism, which would let your improve on this further.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I suspected the crate was a little odd in its design, but wasn't sure due to my lack of experience in Rust. I'll look for something better. FYI, the code panics due to the multiple initialisations of the button, saying `PinNotAvailable(19)`, but the strategy seems to work.

Comment: That second snippet of code prints `Button 1 pressed` and `Button 2 pressed` continuously (without me pressing either buttons) when I run it on my Pi 3.

Comment: thread probably panic and so future is already ready and report None. I'm not sure using try_send make sense.